# Creating a vector with certain values at specific positions based on another vector

Tags: r, vector, replace

If I start with vector1, and test to see which items equal 1:

```
vector1 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)

test <- which(vector1 == 1)
```

test now equals: 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10

then, I want to randomly choose two of the items in test:

```
sample_vector <- sample(test, 2, replace = FALSE)
```

the above code generated a sample_vector: 6, 3

My question is how do I take sample_vector and turn it into:

```
vector2 <- 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I'm essentially looking to assign only the items in sample_vector to equal 1, and the remaining items from vector1 are assigned to equal 0 (i.e. so it looks like vector2). vector2 needs to have the same length at vector1 (10 items).

Thanks!

Comment: `replace(integer(length(vector1)), sample_vector, 1)`

Comment: `tabulate(sample_vector,length(vector1))`

Answer (score 1):

```
vector2 <- rep(0, length(vector1))
vector2[sample_vector] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(44)
vector1 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
test <- which(vector1 == 1)
sample_vector <- sample(test, 2, replace = FALSE)
sample_vector
#[1] 8 3

replace(tabulate(seq_along(vector1)) - 1, sample_vector, 1)
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: `replace` seems to be redundant

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
vector2 <- rep(0,len(vector1))
vector2[sample_vector] = 1
```